# jQuery Drag Drop - how to fetch the dropped value in the server end?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have an application which uses jQuery UI to drag a LI from one UL to another. the asp code for the same is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/ui.core.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jquery-ui-1.5.3.custom.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#selectedUsers").sortable({ connectWith: ["#userList"] });
        $("#userList").sortable({ connectWith: ["#selectedUsers"] });
    });
</script>
```

Tea
                            Coffee
                            Juice
                        
                    
                    
                        User list

```
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDisplay" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
               />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

My question is.. How do I capture the dropped LI element at the server end? I wanted the jQuery to return the id/value of  this dropped LI to the server end..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a "receive" event handler for when the dragged item is received, such as

```
$("#selectedUsers").sortable({ 
    connectWith: ["#userList"],
    receive: function(event, ui) {
       objectMoved(ui.sortable, this);
    }
});

function objectMoved(obj, newContainer) {
   /* here you would either perform some sort of AJAX request,
    * or dynamically add/update a form-field for POSTing if you
    * are doing standard form submission
    */
}
```

You'll also need to attach the same receive event to "userList"

Note that I haven't used the "sortable" ui helper before, but it should be a similar principle to "draggable" and "droppable", and I've based my example on what I know from  these other two helpers - if it's not entirely correct, it should be close.

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly for me... Am using the hidden field in input tag to capture the value of the dropped item. However, i'm not able to actually capture the value of the dragged variable in IE.. It works fine when i do it in Firefox using this peice of code...

```
        $("#userList").bind('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {
            var itemList = ui.originalTarget.innerHTML;
            alert(itemList);
        });
```

I also tried doing this...

alert(ui.item.attr('id'));

However, the windows apparently is not able to recognize the id of the li or the inner html present in the li which is being drag-dropped..

Comment: Hey!

I figured it out....

I just did this...

 $("#userList").bind('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {
                var list = $(this).text();
                alert(list);
            });

Thank you so much anyway!!!